# Why is OAuth2UserService not running for role authorization in Spring Boot under WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, google-oauth, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement roles with Spring Security by following [Spring Security's documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#oauth2login-advanced-oauth2-user-service), but I haven't been able to run the OAuth2UserService.

This is the configuration file that I have and OAuth2UserService, which is following their documentation. The terminal prints `ABC`, but not `DEF` so it's not running when I go to the page "/test" as an example. I'm using Google Identity with OAuth2.

The authentication works, but unfortunately this doesn't. I've tried using `GrantedAuthoritesMapper` and a number of other examples as well, but the same thing happens.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
        .logout(l -> {
            l.logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll();})
        .authorizeRequests(a -> a
            .antMatchers("/", "/js/**", "/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/test").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .csrf(c -> c
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        )
        .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
            .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo -> userInfo
                .userService(this.oauth2UserService()
            ))
        );
    }

private OAuth2UserService<OAuth2UserRequest, OAuth2User> oauth2UserService() {
    final DefaultOAuth2UserService delegate = new DefaultOAuth2UserService();
    System.out.println("ABC");

    return (userRequest) -> {
        System.out.println("DEF");
        OAuth2User oauth2User = delegate.loadUser(userRequest);
        Set<GrantedAuthority> mappedAuthorities = new HashSet<>();

        mappedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));

        oauth2User = new DefaultOAuth2User(mappedAuthorities, 
                oauth2User.getAttributes(), oauth2User.getName());
        return oauth2User;
    };
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The `oauth2UserService` is not called when you go to the page "/test" because it is called after authentication. Do you see `"DEF"` printed after you log in with a user?

Comment: Also it looks like you are not passing the correct parameter to the `DefaultOAuth2User` constructor. The third parameter is the `nameAttributeKey`, the key used to access the user's name from the list of attributes. Instead, you providing the value, not the key.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't found the answer yet, my problem was solved by adding the scope to application.properties file.

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.scope=profile,email
```